# Issue with javascript and setting selected index of a select

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a piece of code that populates a dropdown based on the selection of another dropdown.  This propogates through 4 dropdowns so:

selection -> selection based on 1 -> selection based on 1 & 2 -> selection based on 1, 2, & 3.

My issue is that sometimes the selection only comes up as 1 item, making it such that the user cannot "fire" the onchanged event.  As such, upon population, I want to set the selected index to 0.  Easy peasy, right?

So here's my code (edited to include full javascript function):

```
function FillProject() {
    var BusinessAreaDropDown = document.getElementById("BusinessAreaDropDown");
    var BusinessAreaSelection = BusinessAreaDropDown.options[BusinessAreaDropDown.selectedIndex].text
    var GenericProjectDropDown = document.getElementById("GenericProjectDropDown");

    if (GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex == -1) {
        GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    var GenericProjectSelection = GenericProjectDropDown.options[GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex].text

    @* Get list from C# for GenericProjects matching  *@

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/FillProject',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { BusinessArea: BusinessAreaSelection, GenericProject: GenericProjectSelection },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function (Projects) {
            $("#ProjectDropDown").html("");
            $.each(Projects, function (i, project) {
                $("#ProjectDropDown").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(project).html(project));
            });
}
})
}
```

This generates an error.  If I place an alert after the if statement, it says that the selected index is still -1.  Here's where stuff gets weird.  If I place an alert INSIDE the if statement it pops up saying that the selected index is -1 before changing, 0 after changing, and actually changes the selectedIndex to 0, causing the code to work.  If I remove the alert statement, it goes back to failing.  What's happening here?

Examples:

Works->

```
if (GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex == -1) {
    alert(GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex);
    GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Works->

```
if (GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex == -1) {
    GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
    alert(GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex);
}
```

Fails ->

```
if (GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex == -1) {
    GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the `jquery` tag as it is completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: GenericProjectDropDown.selectedIndex == -1 can't be true

Comment: is there any ajax involved with this? It sounds like an asynchronous operation problem and alert is letting the asynchronous part finish

Comment: @Wintermute, if the `select` element has no options, its `selectedIndex` is -1.  However, you couldn't then change it to 0 as the OP is attempting to do.

Comment: `selectedIndex == -1` occurs when a select element has no options  Could you provide more  detail on what you are doing when you run into this problem? How can you not check if there is only one option when you add them?

Comment: @charlietfl There is ajax involved, yes.  Is there a way I can make sure that the ajax waits until this value is set?  I'll update the post with full code.

Comment: no, you need to work within the ajax callback. Need to see full code context

Comment: @Trakto53 Essentially, if someone selects an element from the first dropdown, I want all 4 boxes to populate, based on the first element in the list.  as charlietfl pointed out, I think it has to do with ajax being asynchronous and the previous ajax statement filling the 2nd dropdown has not yet completed.  Is there an ajax.Wait or something I can use?  Sorry for my complete noobery.

Answer (score 0):

Solution!  Thanks to @charlietfl

I had some ajax that was running in a previous code chunk populating the dropdown and it wasn't finixshed before running the second script because it was asynchronous.  By adding:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/FillProject',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: false,      //this line 
    data: { BusinessArea: BusinessAreaSelection, GenericProject: GenericProjectSelection },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function (Projects) {
        $("#ProjectDropDown").html("");
        $.each(Projects, function (i, project) {
            $("#ProjectDropDown").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(project).html(project));
        });
```

The issue was resolved!